# How to delete rows from pandas without mentioning index value, as i have duplicate index values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 rows with the same index value, I need to delete one row based on a column['year'] value,., which should be equal to 2018, as of now.
It won't be 2018 all the time, Hence I need to update it automatically, based on the output from another query... Could someone help me regarding this

the output of a query in which 'vHe2' column <=0

[image: output of a query in which 'vHe2' column <=0]

when checked with index number to drop, found duplicate index values

[image: when checked with index number to drop, found duplicate index values]

Comment: Could you please be more specific? All rows in your example data frame contain 2018, then what other criteria you will apply to remove the row?

Comment: (1) reindex, so you won't have duplicate index values (2) drop rows, per new, unique indexes. Having duplicate index values is rather bad idea.

Comment: Thank you i  tried to reindex it, so that it didnt had any duplicate index  values.  and then i performed deletion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
data_y1 = data_y1[(data_y1.index != 719) | (data_y1['year'] != 2018)]
```